# Could not find gem 'ruby (= 2.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm currently using Ubuntu to run my ruby on rails applications, but I just got this error message: 
"Could not find gem 'ruby (= 2.0.0) ruby' in the gems available on this machine."
every time I typed in "rails server". I tried to reinstall everything but it's still there. What does this even mean? The only gem for ruby is 0.1.0, why there is a 2.0.0 ruby gem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a line in your `Gemfile` like `gem 'ruby', '=2.0.0'`?

It should be:

```
ruby "2.0.0"
```

Comment: yeah, I have it like this: gem 'ruby','2.0.0'

Comment: There's no such thing as the Ruby gem, the one that's there [is some kind of plug for a bug](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby). Instead specify with the `ruby` directive.

Comment: @wuxi9007, Consider abandoning whatever rails tutorial you are reading.

Comment: @7stud, I'm reading "learning rails by example by Michael Harlt", I think it's Ok. You got some recommendation?

Comment: That's an error if it was in the original material.

Comment: @wuxi9007, You mean "Ruby on Rails Tutorial".  The "Learn Rails by Example" part is a subtitle.  Do you have the printed version?  Is that a typo? Or did you copy it wrong? I'm currently reading the online version, and if you look here: https://www.railstutorial.org/book/demo_app#code-demo_gemfile_sqlite_version_redux, at Listing 2.1, you can see that the top part of the Gemfile is a bit different than the rest of the Gemfile--it consists of a link, the ruby version, and a gemset comment for rvm.

Comment: *You got some recommendation?*  Well, this is my third time trying it, and I've never gotten past Chapter 6.  Django?

Comment: @7stud I don't think learning Python and a new framework is the best response to not liking one of many books on Rails.

Comment: @7stud, exactly as you said. I'm reading "Ruby on Rails Tutorial", fourth edition, online version. Yeah, details are pretty clear at the top of the Gemfile. I'm just not familiar with the exact format of Gemfile. Are you reading this to build your web, too?

Comment: @wuxi9007, **I'm just not familiar with the exact format of Gemfile.**   There is a lot of copying involved, and you have to get it right.  The problem with the tutorial is this: after you read a chapter, could you erase everything, and then construct everything anew without looking at the book?  If you can't, have you learned anything?

Comment: @7stud, oh, the tutorial for me is to teach me how this system works, and what I'm going to do is based on it, so it's inevitable.